# Почему аргумент функции SLfree типа char*?

Tags: c, linux

Работаю с библиотекой `newt`. Она использует функциии библиотеки `slang`.

При исполнении кода возникает ошибка работы с памятью. Дело все в функции SLfree:

```
void SLfree (SLFUTURE_VOID *s)
{
   if (s != NULL) free (s);
}
```

Дело в том, что флаг `ENABLE_SLFUTURE_VOID` не выставлен, а во всех функциях идет приведение к типу `char*`. Но функция `free` ведь имеет аргумент типа `void`. При исполнении кода на машине возникает ошибка.

```
#ifdef ENABLE_SLFUTURE_VOID
# define SLFUTURE_VOID void
#else
# define SLFUTURE_VOID char
#endif
```

Почему это делается (приведение к типу char*)?

Comment: Ошибка наверняка не в этом: free все равно какого типа указатель, лишь бы указывал куда надо. На уровне инструкций процессора указатель - 32(64)-битное число и никакой информации о типе нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция free освобождает память, адрес которой задан в ее аргументе. Указатель любого типа может быть неявно преобразован к указателю типа `void *`.

Например,

```
int i = 65;
char c = 'A';

int *pi = &i;
char *pc = &c;

void *pv;

pv = pi;
pv = pc;
```

Ошибка в функции, которую вы показали, может возникнуть из-за того, что указатель не содержит корректный адрес динамически выделенной памяти.

Согласно стандарту C (6.2.5 Types):

> 28 A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as a pointer to a character type.

И там же дается сноска

> 48) The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to
>   imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from
>   functions, and members of unions.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду искать...